# Issue with input of char variables

Tags: c++

I have this code snippet of a main function in C++ Programming Language. I want to have two distinct copies of integer and chars. But after the input of integer 'a and b' the char inputs of 'a and b' are performed but when I check their declaration point in Visual Studio 2019 by clicking Ctrl and clicking on the variable it takes me to the declaration of their integer types. How do I take inputs of the char type declared above without changing the variables names.
Please Help

[image]

Comment: Too much vital information is in an image. This makes the question "Not Useful" to too many people. Please replace the image with text.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay, i found the answer to this myself. We can resolve this issue by defining the char variables inside a different scope. This way we can override the shadowing situation as explained above.
Follow the below screenshot to understand what I mean to say.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's fine. Typically you'd want to just name the character variables differently.

Comment: Same as with the question. Replace the image with text, please.